# Blazemeter Taurus Increment variable

Tags: junit, load-testing, blazemeter, taurus

I would like to perform a PUT test with BZT, but its not clear how to use a dynamic variable, for example a count function where I am using the execution number as the variable when making a put to a database.

Answer (score 0):

[Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) is only a wrapper performing configuration, launching and results processing of the underlying [Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ExecutionSettings/#Executor-Types).

So you need to refer to the particular Executor documentation to learn how to implement the "counter" there.

Taurus default executor is [JMeter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/) which means that the "requests" you specify declaratively in [YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) are translated into JMeter [.jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)

So the most straightforward solution would be using JMeter's [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function where required so if you put the function call like `${__counter(,)}` into your script - it will generate an incremented number each time it will be called.

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)